# fopen() to support large files and UNICODE filenames

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, unicode, fopen

I am trying to write a patch that supports files with UNICODE names and has size larger than 2GB. I know _wfopen() is UNICODE equivalent of fopen() and fopen64() supports large files. My question is how can one achieve both, that is to support UNICODE names of a file that has size greater than 2GB.

Comment: I don't believe there's any size limitation built into `_wfopen`; it should be able to open large files. 2GB threshold only matters when you seek and tell - for that, there's `_fseeki64` and `_ftelli64`

Comment: Or, you could simply use the Win32 `CreateFileW()` and `SetFilePointer/Ex()` functions directly instead, which the C functions will end up calling internally anyway

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Your comment helps, I created my helper to open with _wfopen and pointed to seek64 and tell64. If you could add it to answer I would be happy to accept it. Thank you!